# problem compiling ale-py on raspberry pi 4 8GB

Tags: python, setup.py, python-wheel

so I'm really new to python programming. I want to install stable_baselines3. For that I already needed to compile (a wheel it's called I think?) for torch cause its only available for 64bit systems. That went easily without a problem following [this](https://github.com/Kashu7100/pytorch-armv7l) instruction.

Now to ale-py. Since the pip-installation gets the same error (`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ale-py==0.7.3 (from versions: )`), I tried to compile it the same ways as before, following the instructions given above. I downloaded it from [the official git repository](https://github.com/mgbellemare/Arcade-Learning-Environment). But running `python setup.py bdist_wheel` left me with the following error message:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/home/pi/Downloads/Arcade-Learning-Environment', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DPython3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/pi/Downloads/Arcade-Learning-Environment/build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.7/ale_py/', '-DSDL_SUPPORT=ON', '-DSDL_DYNLOAD=ON', '-DBUILD_CPP_LIB=OFF', '-DBUILD_PYTHON_LIB=ON']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Googling that hasn't brought up any results so I wondered if anyone here could help me, I would be very thankful.

Thanks in advance and have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken but I think running `sudo apt install cmake` might help. Also if you are intending to use python 3.9 you should use pip3 and python3 instead of pip and python. pip and python will, instead, use python 2.7